# What is the down side to encapsulating my crawl space and installing a dehumidifier

Tags: flooring

Moisture and insulation are the main reason for considering encapsulating

Comment: climate zone?  crawl space floor type?

Comment: It'll do nothing for insulation, outside of giving you another set of walls to add another layer of insulation.  Air will convect inside the space, causing thermal bridging through it.  However, the dehumidifier will act as a space heater, causing 100% of its energy consumption to enter the space as heat.

Answer (score 2):

Given that your question does not give details, I will assume that it is a dirt floor in the crawl space, and wood floors up above. And you are trying to avoid moisture and especially mold. Encapsulation by itself really does not address insulation, although it may allow you to insulate now in a sealed and relatively dry environment. If you are having issues, the positives will probably outweigh the negatives in my opinion. That said:

Obvious first one is cost to do it well, because doing it poorly will be a total mess. Use good material and do a good job to seal the material to all walls, supports and anything else that my stick through. And close and seal any other vents, air gaps. If you are having issues now, it is almost certain that you will need to install water channels and drains (inside and out) and possibly pumps - and if pumps, you may need backup pumps and power. Then maintain it. This can be a chore, especially if you need to crawl around down there. You do not want to get water on top of your encapsulation. It will no longer drain into the soil easily, even it it is sloped towards a drain.

And then power and drain for the dehumidifier.

Is your furnace there (or anything else) using air from the crawl space? If so you just blocked it's air supply so you need to bring in fresh air to it, or you will have big problems with fumes. This can be complicated....  Depending on the house and condition, you may still need some sort of vent, or a way to create negative pressure in the crawl space to ensure air does not go from the crawl space into the living space. This will keep smells from building up there. This will create more work for the dehumidifier. I assume any radon issues will need to be addressed if they have not been already, but you are now changing from a vented space to a sealed space, so make sure this is addressed by some sort of active ventilation if this is an issue in your area.

If you have rats or mice, they will chew through it, so you need to clean, inspect and repair.

If you store stuff down there, you need to be careful not to tear the material.

I hear it is possible that if you have wood floors, they may now have a high moisture content and when you dry out below the floor, it will shrink the wood. I imagine it is possible that this would impact all the other wood supports in the house also. Something to be aware of and watch for.